# Individual and "Team" access to list items

Tags: 2013, list, groups, sharepoint-on-prem, item-level-permissions

We have a list of service requests. Anyone in the enterprise can create a request and then edit their request as the process moves along.

We now have the user need to allow "teams" to access each other's requests so that they can cover for each other during vacation or illness. I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this. I was thinking of creating a sharepoint group for each of the teams, but then I'm not sure how I would manage allowing the members of the groups to see other list items.

The people who use the site are not SP experts and they shouldn't need to be to do their jobs. Therefore I want to keep the mechanics of this transparent for them, that is to say, normal form create, edit, submit, and so forth should handle this for them. They shouldn't have to go in and do permissions or create special views etc.

Our team has Site Collection level access to SharePoint so nothing involving central-admin access or custom deployed code. All needs to be from the UI or client-side code -- csr, rest, javascript, etc.

This doesn't have to be actual permission level-based security -- there isn't anything all that important in these requests. So it could be managed by only showing the links to requests to the appropriate people.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter a column based on user group membership using below CAML

```
<Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups"><FieldRef Name="NameOfYourColumn"/></Membership>
```

You can create a people column in your list that contains either the current user name or the SharePoint group that represents the team. You can then create a normal view and update the query using SharePoint designer to include above CAML as part of the query. This would only show items if the current user is mentioned in the column either directly or part of the a group that the user is member of. While editing the view in SharePoint designer you may have to swith to advanced edit mode.

If your application involves custom pages built using javascript then all you have to do is add an AND clause with below CAML to get filtered list of items.

Comment: Just to be sure I'm doing this right....I just put that bit between the <Where></Where> I don't need an <eq>? Do you have a link to any other documentation of the magical CAML things like this? (I'm already familiar with basic stuff, but had not see the <membership> element before.

Comment: Found a link to this specific trick Found a link to this specific trick https://sympmarc.com/2010/06/16/caml-filter-for-current-group-membership/

Comment: You can also take a look at this link http://www.andypierre.info/post/SharePoint-Filter-on-Current-Users-Group-Membership1 . You probably need an AND or OR clause depending on view filter you are trying to customize.