# Only manager can view and edit the created items by his team

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, 2016

I have a vacation list and each employee can only view and edit his created vacation items.

how can allow the manager to view and edit only requests from his team?

is it possible as OOTB? I don't have good experience in code!!

I can't use SharePoint designer!

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248518/individual-and-team-access-to-list-items/248520#248520) , you can implement something similar.

Comment: thank you, in my situation it doesn't help, it allows any one in this group to see all items! I need only the manager to see the vacations requests from his team and others can't see it

Comment: Can you not populate the people and group field with the user and his manager instead of a group.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get your point!

Comment: You could create a column that contains the current user and his manager. Then you can create a view with membership element that shows items for current user. Manger would be able to see all his team items as his is added to that column.

Comment: I don't have a group to use member element, I can't use SharePoint designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to do the following:**

- Create a group `Managers Group` for all managers with `edit` permission.
- Assign this group to your list.
- Edit your list, add a new People Picker column `Assigned To Manager`.
- Create a new view to filter by `Assigned To Manager` = **[ME]**.
- Now create a new page, add this list view.
- Edit the list view web part and at the `Target audience` add the `Managers Group`.
- Now everyone in `Managers Group` can **only** view/Edit

  - The List view web part.
  - The Assigned requests.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the item-level permissions setting in your list to only allow employee's to view and edit their own requests? If so, you can provide the manager 'Design' level permissions (or above) to the list which will allow them to view and manage all items. There's a nice write-up of this configuration using almost the same scenario as an example on this blog - https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/.

Cheers,

-Drew

Comment: Thank you, the vacation list for all managers, I want each manager can only see his team requests, your answer will allow the manager to see all requests from others team